# Completing "Discerning The Transmundane" with a clear conscience

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The "Discerning The Transmundane" quest requires me to "harvest" the following:

- Orc Blood
- Falmer Blood
- Dark Elf Blood
- Wood Elf Blood
- High Elf Blood

However I prefer to only kill in self-defence. Is it possible to complete this quest without killing in cold blood, and if so what is the easiest way of doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is entirely possible to complete it with a clear conscience, it's just going to take much longer than normal. Most, if not all of the races needed will be in a position to attack you at some point in the game. Here's a list of the races, and some possible examples:

- Orc Blood: During the daedric quest [The Cursed Tribe](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Cursed_Tribe)
- Falmer Blood: Can easily be found inside [Dwemer ruins](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwemer_Ruins)
- Dark Elf Blood: Many vampires or magicians found in dungeons are dark elves.
- Wood Elf Blood: Wood elves are very common bandits, usually posted on guard towers. Also, the random thief encounter (the one who demands you give him money) is most often a wood elf.
- High Elf Blood: During the main quest [Diplomatic Immunity](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Diplomatic_Immunity) you will fight Thalmor (High Elves) almost exclusively.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go all the way through liar's retreat. All the blood types except a high elves will be there. The orc will be behind a locked door. The high elf (altmer) will be in halted stream camp. If you go into the mine, straight across to the back exit, a dead high elf will be laying in the pit.

Answer (score 0):

You can harvest blood from corpses that are already dead, and there are plenty lying around. Some are more common than others but it's possible to complete the quest without killing a single mer yourself.

If you're willing to cheat, the UESP Wiki has a [list of places](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane) where pre-dead corpses can be found. If you want to look for yourself, the best places to look are dungeons with their own built-in protection of their own. Bandits camping out in ancient ruins often get killed by the resident draugr, and falmer are often killed off by the dwemer machines.

You can also take advantage of things like vampire or dragon attacks in towns that have a sufficiently large mer population.

Of course, if you just take a bunch of radiant quests to clear out bandit lairs, you'll inevitably end up killing plenty of the correct races just by playing. IIRC the only one I had to actually look around for was Altmer, as mer bandits tend to be mostly Bosmer and Dunmer.